# Unable to restore backup from iCloud in iPhone 12 pro max

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore

I have a big-time issue with restoring a Backup from iCloud to my new iPhone.

1. I traded the iPhone 6s and bought iPhone 12 Pro Max
2. before trading I took backup of all my data on iCloud, then reset it and traded.
3. When I started up the new iPhone 12 Pro Max, I got an option under App & Data to restore data from iCloud
4. I successfully signed in but later it showed `No Backups Available` however, I could see the data on iCloud in a browser.
5. I did not take backup using iTunes, hence could not restore it from my PC.

Here is the status of my iCloud backup, it says incomplete too. But not sure if this is the case than will I able to take the backup again that exists on iCloud ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe the notification that the backup is incomplete at 12.1GB means there _isn't_ a successful backup on iCloud, that's why you get the error message that there are `No Backups Available`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can erase your new phone and run the setup again. Apple cloud servers are seeing outages and general slowdowns around product launches this week so I would check them before trying a restore.

- https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

You need these to be working for a restore: App Store, Apple ID, iCloud Account & Sign In, iCloud Backup, iOS Device Activation.

Others may be needed depending on your settings and expectations.  Your process is solid and there’s not much you can do - whatever is in iCloud is all you can get so hopefully it’s just slow internet and you don’t have to get Apple Engineering involved to look at your backup logs and perhaps fix or deliver news on what can be restored at this point.

Comment: I referred to the link that you had provided , and it seems all services that you had mentioned are in GREEN so does it mean services are up and running

Comment: It means they are not down, but I don’t think all are running fast from what I can tell. App downloads seem very slow to me, but the link says, if they are green call Apple if you get an error @Hunt

Comment: i talked to apple support team and the clearly said that as the back was incomplete they are unable to fetch the backup option in phone and hence its throwing an error "No Backups Available"